# How to use mmap iteratively to map data in small chunks from a large file

Tags: c, system, igraph, system-calls, mmap

The vector `order` in the following program consumes 8MB when loaded. I'm trying to perform memory mapping using `mmap` and map a small `CHUNK_SIZE`iteratively to avoid memory overhead. The `CHUNK_SIZE`is `10240` and the program causes segmentation fault when accessing the index `11264` as `VECTOR(*order)[act_rank++] = actvect;`.

Now, I have the following questions:

1. After the first invocation of the function `memory_map_order_iterative()`, (without iterative or 2nd invocation) how the vector can access up to index `11263` where the chunk size is `10240`?
2. When invoking the function `memory_map_order_iterative()` (iteratively), after 2nd invocation the order vector should be accessed from index `10240` to `20479`, then why it is causing segmentation fault?

Any suggestions will be a great help.

```
#include <igraph.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define CHUNK_SIZE 10240

igraph_error_t unmap_order(igraph_integer_t **mapped_order, igraph_integer_t chunk_size){
    if (munmap(*mapped_order, chunk_size * sizeof(igraph_integer_t)) == -1) {
        perror("munmap");
        return IGRAPH_EFILE;
    }
    *mapped_order = NULL;
    return IGRAPH_SUCCESS;
}

igraph_error_t memory_map_order_iterative(igraph_vector_int_t *order, const char *order_filename, igraph_integer_t **mapped_order, igraph_integer_t no_of_elements, igraph_integer_t *remaining_elements, igraph_integer_t *offset) {
    int fd;

    fd = open(order_filename, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("open");
        return IGRAPH_EFILE;
    }

    if (ftruncate(fd, no_of_elements * sizeof(igraph_integer_t)) == -1) {
        perror("ftruncate");
        close(fd);
        return IGRAPH_EFILE;
    }

    igraph_integer_t chunk_size = (*remaining_elements > CHUNK_SIZE) ? CHUNK_SIZE : *remaining_elements;

    *mapped_order = mmap(NULL, chunk_size * sizeof(igraph_integer_t), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, (*offset) * sizeof(igraph_integer_t));
    if (*mapped_order == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap");
        close(fd);
        return IGRAPH_EFILE;
    }

    *offset += chunk_size;
    *remaining_elements -= chunk_size;

    close(fd);

    igraph_vector_int_view(order, *mapped_order, chunk_size);

    return IGRAPH_SUCCESS;
}

igraph_error_t igraph_bfs(const igraph_t *graph,
               igraph_vector_int_t *order,
               void *extra) {

    const igraph_integer_t no_of_nodes = igraph_vcount(graph);

    igraph_dqueue_int_t Q;
    igraph_integer_t actroot = 0;
    igraph_integer_t act_rank = 0;

    IGRAPH_DQUEUE_INT_INIT_FINALLY(&Q, 100);

    igraph_integer_t *mapped_order = NULL;
    igraph_integer_t remaining_elements = 999998;
    igraph_integer_t offset = 0;
    igraph_error_t is_map_success;

    is_map_success = memory_map_order_iterative(order, "/tmp/orders_map.bin", &mapped_order, no_of_nodes, &remaining_elements, &offset);
    if (is_map_success != IGRAPH_SUCCESS) {
        return is_map_success;
    }

    while (1) {
        IGRAPH_CHECK(igraph_dqueue_int_push(&Q, actroot));
        IGRAPH_CHECK(igraph_dqueue_int_push(&Q, 0));

        while (!igraph_dqueue_int_empty(&Q)) {
            igraph_integer_t actvect = igraph_dqueue_int_pop(&Q);

            if (order) {
                if(act_rank>0 && act_rank%CHUNK_SIZE==0){
                    igraph_error_t unmap_error = unmap_order(&mapped_order, CHUNK_SIZE);
                    if (unmap_error != IGRAPH_SUCCESS) {
                        return unmap_error;
                    }
                    igraph_error_t is_map_success;
                    is_map_success = memory_map_order_iterative(order, "/tmp/orders_map.bin", &mapped_order, no_of_nodes, &remaining_elements, &offset);
                    if (is_map_success != IGRAPH_SUCCESS) {
                        return is_map_success;
                    }
                }
                VECTOR(*order)[act_rank++] = actvect;
            }
        }
    }
    return IGRAPH_SUCCESS;
}

int main(void) {

    igraph_t graph;
    FILE *file = fopen("random_graph.edgelist", "r");
    if (!file) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (igraph_read_graph_edgelist(&graph, file, 0, IGRAPH_UNDIRECTED) == IGRAPH_SUCCESS) {
    } else {
        return 1;
    }

    igraph_vector_int_t order;

    igraph_vector_int_init(&order, 0);

    igraph_bfs(&graph, &order,/*extra=*/ NULL);

    igraph_destroy(&graph);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm expecting to map `order` using `mmap` and access it chunk by chunk as
chunk1: from 0 to 10239
chunk1: from 10240 to 20479
and so on.

I tried mapping the full length of the `order` without mapping chunk by chunk as given below it works well and doesn't get segmentation fault. The issue is mapping the full length of order doesn't reduce memory consumption.

```
void unmap(igraph_integer_t *mapped_order, size_t size) {
    if (munmap(mapped_order, size) == -1) {
        perror("munmap");
    }
}

igraph_error_t memory_map_order(const char *order_filename, igraph_integer_t **mapped_order, igraph_integer_t no_of_elements, igraph_vector_int_t *order) {
    int fd;

    fd = open(order_filename, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("open");
        return IGRAPH_EFILE;
    }

    if (ftruncate(fd, no_of_elements * sizeof(igraph_integer_t)) == -1) {
        perror("ftruncate");
        close(fd);
        return IGRAPH_EFILE;
    }

    *mapped_order = mmap(NULL, no_of_elements * sizeof(igraph_integer_t), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (*mapped_order == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap");
        close(fd);
        return IGRAPH_EFILE;
    }

    close(fd);

    igraph_vector_int_view(order, *mapped_order, no_of_elements);

    return IGRAPH_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need to do this in the first place. Mapping memory has very little overhead, the size of the mapping doesn't make it more expensive.

Comment: You're doing `lseek(fd,some_offset,...)` and then doing `mmap(...,fd,some_offset)` I've never seen that before. I'd simplify by leaving off the `lseek` and just do the `mmap`. You can map _just_ a portion by doing `mmap(...,segment_length,...,fd,segment_offset)` and doing `munmap` on that when you're done. For an example, see my answer: [Share portion/area of mmap'ed memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73311499/5382650)

Comment: @Barmar Yes, it's mostly useful for mapping an (e.g.) 8GB file under a 32 bit system.

Comment: Right. Come back to us when the file size is in GB, not MB.

Comment: @CraigEstey I already tried removing the `lseek` but that doesn't fix the issue. Anyway, thank you both for your response

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your suggestion. But if you can help fix it before it becomes GB and crashes that will be great.

Comment: Is your data size really likely to grow by 3 orders of magnitude? If not, don't waste your time worrying about it. If this problem is specific to igraph, I don't know anything about it.

Comment: It is not specific to igraph